# Unable to install python-fingerprint module o Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, fingerprint

I am trying to install python-fingerprint module on Raspberry Pi OS.previously I installed same on raspbian os.It works with same command **sudo apt-get install python-fingerprint**

But now it failed with dependencies python-serial and python-pil
check attached screenshot for referrence.
please guide [image]

Comment: Can you provide the verbose log? Sounds like a repository issue. A formatted text version of the error would be helpful

Comment: @Ramhound how to enable verbose logging ?